# How to match digits followed by a dot using sed?

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to use `sed` to substitute all the patterns with digits followed immediately by a dot (such as `3.`, `355.`) by an empty string. So I try:

```
sed 's/\d+\.//g' file.txt
```

But it doesn't work. Why is that?

Comment: I found [this article](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) very useful

Answer (score 226, accepted):

Because sed is not perl -- sed regexes do not have a `\d` shorthand:

```
sed 's/[[:digit:]]\+\.//g'
```

sed regular expression documentation [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html#Regular-Expressions).

Comment: That's if you want *zero* or more digits. `/[[:digit:]]*\. /` will match the string `foo.` because you allow for zero digits. If you want *one* or more use `\+` as shown

Answer (score 127):

Two problems:

1. `sed` does not support `\d`. Use `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]`.
2. `+` must be backslashed to get the special meaning: `\+`.

Comment: instead of backslashing the + (which doesn't work on Mac OS X, for example) you can use the -E option to `interpret regular expressions as extended (modern) regular expressions rather than basic regular expressions (BRE's).` Sadly, this doesn't help with the \d issue...

Comment: @gmale: `-E` does not work for GNU sed, it uses `-r` instead.

Comment: Okay... it sure looks like `sed` just sucks when it comes to portability...

Comment: @choroba I think I confused myself today. I'm going to delete my noisy comments...

Comment: Basically, what I was trying to warn people about is: If you do not use extended regex (`-E` on BSD sed and `-r` on GNU sed), in BSD sed, neither `+` nor `\+` (same with `?`) will work at all, whereas in GNU sed you can get them to work with the backslash. Hence the common recommendation to use extended regex in scripting

Comment: The question of whether `-E` can be relied upon in linux to do the same as `-r` is what's unclear to me now.

Comment: I'd just use Perl :-)

Comment: When you are in a real hurry and all you can find are posts like this, but they never explain the meaning of , or +.

Comment: At the risk of sounding patronising, if you don't know what `+` does, you don't need SE but a tutorial for basics

Answer (score 13):

Adding to the other answers a few years later, I found I wanted the extended feature for a more complex regex

This expects simply `+` for one or more, and generally made the string more obvious to me for both my case and this one

```
# NOTE \d is not supported
sed --regexp-extended 's/[0-9]+\.//g'
```

[`-E` `-r` `--regexp-extended` are all the same](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Command_002dLine-Options)

Using `sed` 4.7

Answer (score 7):

The sed man page references the re_format man page. It makes 2 distinctions: (1) obsolete versus extended regular expressions; (2) non-enhanced versus enhanced regular expressions. All 4 combinations are possible. There is support in sed for both obsolete and extended, but in either case only for non-enhanced. The \d operator is a feature of enhanced regular expressions, therefore not supported by sed.